# Difference between "девушка", "девочка" and "подруга"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выбор-слова

So, if I remember correctly, "девушка" can refer to both "girl" (of any age) or "girlfriend" (I'm not entirely sure of this, so feel free to call me out). But what about 'подруга'? Can I safely replace 'девушка' with 'подруга'? Which of these should I use if I'm talking about a coworker of mine?

Comment: Related: [What kind of “girlfriend” is meant by “подруга”?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13883/what-kind-of-girlfriend-is-meant-by-подруга/13884#13884)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`Подруга`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0) is the feminine form of "friend", `друг` and can mean, depending on the context, both: either just a friend or a girlfriend (though this is figurative and obsolete).

[`Девушка`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0) is a girl from the age of puberty to womanhood. The other meaning is indeed `girlfriend`, but keep in mind that it can't be used to talk about dating someone who's in her, say, forties (which is no problem in English) - this will sound slightly off.

[`Девочка`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) is just a little girl. Sometimes women refer to themselves as `девочки` ("ну мы же девочки, нам можно плакать") but this is nothing but a figure of speech. The other meaning would be something close to English `babe` ("моя хорошая девочка").

These words have different meanings, and while they *are* related, they're by no means interchangeable.

Comment: How obsolete do you think подруга is in the sense of "girlfriend"? My friends of around 8 years ago used it all the time without any Russians seeming to think it odd.

Comment: @Wilson "Подруга" nowadays is mostly used among females as their equivalent of "друг" ("friend"). Often, when a man calls a woman "подруга", it is to make it clear that there is no romantic relationship between the two: "just friends" (as we know, men and women can't be "just friends", but whatever, maybe somewhat closer than a mere colleague/acquaintance). Yet on the other hand, the word can be used as "girlfriend", not _that_ common, but not exactly obsolete, either.

Comment: "Девушка" with possessive pronoun ("Моя девушка", "его девушка") means girlfriend ("My girlfriend", "his girlfriend"). "Девушка" without possessive pronoun is just "Girl".

Comment: @Alexander That sounds like a good way to distinguish between the two. Although I would add "with [either explicit or implicit] possessive pronoun", because it is often omitted.

Comment: There's also `подружка`

Comment: `"Девушка" with possessive pronoun` - exactly how it is in English. "My girl" vs "a girl" - the same. www.metrolyrics.com/supergirl-lyrics-reamonn.html

Comment: I think you should explain that девушка is a diminutive of дева (maid, virgin). And so it would generally not be polite to refer to an unmarried girl as малодая женшина (young woman) since this suggests a lack of belief in her virginity. You do imply this by contrasting the status of a девушка with "womanhood", but readers may not understand that by "womanhood" you mean the status a maid acquires on her wedding night when she ceases to be a maid.

Answer (score 12):

As a native Russian speaker, I wanted to drop a couple of comments...

`Девушка` means "girlfriend" if and only if it comes with a possessive (pro)noun, for example: "моя девушка", "Васина девушка", "Девушка брата".

Regarding the obsolescence of `подруга` in the sense of "girlfriend", I would disagree. A wise and cautious man keeps this word in his lexicon and uses it when he's not yet comfortable calling her "моя девушка". She'll be somewhat unhappy to hear you call her "подруга", but may actually respect you more. That basically builds another barrier on her way to your resources.

Comment: Downvote for sexism in the last paragraph.

Comment: What a ridiculous assertion about women. Downvote!

Answer (score 4):

"Which of these should I use if I'm talking about a coworker of mine?"

This part of the original question was left unanswered.
A female coworker is called "сотрудница", or you can say "девушка с моей работы" for a young lady, and "женщина с моей работы" for an older one.

Comment: A female coworker is called "коллега", no one calls  their coworkers "сотрудница", it's a word used by management. However, good point, we all indeed forgot to cover this part of the question. Welcome to the Russian SE )

Answer (score -2):

A friend - ["one attached to another by feelings of personal regard and preference"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/friend#etymonline_v_14179) - ПРИЯТЕЛЬ по-русски, from ПРИЯТНО/ПРИЯТНОЕ - something that give a pleased feelings or preference.

Есть разница между дружбой, приятельскими отношениями, деловыми отношения и тп.

К ДРУГу ближе слово ~comrade(соратник), так как этимологически слово ДРУГ связано со словом ДРУЖИНа, то есть соратник(comrade-in-arms), дружить~служить(в боевом отряде). Для ДРУЖБЫ важно не столько общее приятное общение, сколько взаимопонимание и ДОВЕРИЕ - trustful relations. Друг - a one, that can give to thee, not a pleased feelings only, but a support, but can be honest and can give a true feedback - to trust and to understand an other is more important, that be pleased. Другой - an other, that you not trust and not understand by 100%, but a one close person.

> Дружба крепкая не сломается,
>
> Не расклеится от дождей и вьюг.
>
> **Друг в беде не бросит**, лишнего не спросит
>
> -Вот что значит настоящий верный друг. Шаинский, детская песенка.

[Песня о друге. Владимир Высоцкий.](https://www.culture.ru/poems/19756/pesnya-o-druge)(a song from the movie-film "Vertical", about alpinists)

> Если друг оказался вдруг
>
> И не друг, и не враг, а — так;
>
> Если сразу не разберешь,
>
> Плох он или хорош,
>
> — Парня в горы тяни — рискни!
>
> Не бросай одного его:
>
> поймешь, кто такой...
>
> ...Если шел он с тобой, как в бой,
>
> На вершине стоял хмельной, —
>
> Значит, как на себя самого,
>
> Положись на него!

Подруга - a woman, a maiden, a girl which thou **trust** and which trusts to thee.

In slang подруга - mean girlfriend.

Девушка - most close is maiden. Maiden - unmarried woman (usually young) - general meaning; virgin - about sexual status, usually in medicine view point; girl - девушка, а не парень; maidservant(in 19 century, and after 1990).

Девочка - a girl, that not a boy), about child status usually, but in jargon or a joking talk can have meaning of a maiden or a virgin.

Extra:

Male - самец, female - самка. В русском языке не называют людей по аналогии с животными по сексуальному статусу - самец и самка, - эти характеристики будут считаться минимум грубостью максимум оскорблением, по отношению к человеку. Поэтому только: мужчина и женщина(usually > 30 years old or she, that has babies already or in pregnant status, женщина~mother) , парень и девушка(~17-30 of old), мальчик и девочка(less, then 17 usually) - в зависимости от возраста.

Иногда замужнюю женщину (уже с детьми) могут шутя называть девушкой, делая комплимент не только её возрасту или внешнему виду, сколько юности её души. Если назвать девушку или женщину девочкой, то это будет акцент на умалении взрослых функций, возможно, с позиции заботы или позиции доминирования с акцентом на её интеллектуальной незрелости (девочка~глупышка).

Your question: Can I safely replace 'девушка' with 'подруга'?

Не всегда, девушка - нейтральное и иногда комплиментарное именование по отношению к дамам. А подруга - это более личное и может звучать фамильярно и неуместно, если эта девушка малознакома и не с ней не установлено доверительных, честных отношений. К мужчинам лучше обращаться "мужчина" или "молодой человек". "Молодой человек" будет звучать комплиментарно и уместно почти всегда.

Если же это "**well knowed/knowed someone**" - тот, кого хорошо знаешь и кто хорошо знает тебя, того **можно называть подруга или друг**, это будет уместно. Но при личном обращении друзей называют по имени или эпитетами вроде "дорогой, милый", к близким можно обратиться "друг мой" вроде французского mon cher, независимо от пола: Друг мой, Анна. Подруга-друг, подружка-дружище обычно употребляют, когда просят помочь или подсказать что-то, потому что у**друж**ить - бескорыстно помочь, либо составить компанию в каком-то деле. Соответственно, обращение с просьбой бескорыстной помощи или без помощи по долгу службы/работы может быть неуместным, если этот человек не ваш близкий знакомый, малоизвестный вам лично, или если человек находится на работе/службе. **Дружить** - проявлять **милость(be mercy, God's forgiveness of his creatures  offenses, to give protection, to care about someone without a reward waiting)** друг к другу.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148549/discussion-on-answer-by--difference-between---and-); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.